# How to add ManyToOne field in android when using the create method in Odoo

Tags: java, android, odoo

I'm new to Odoo mobile api's and im currently trying to create a meeting within an opportunity. I have created an opportunity as follows:

```
 OdooValues values = new OdooValues();
    values.put("name", "App Testing");
    values.put("revenue_amount_currency", 100);
    values.put("probability", 45);


    client.create("crm.lead", values, new IOdooResponse() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(OdooResult result) {
            int serverId = result.getInt("result");
            Log.d("Opportunity Id", String.valueOf(serverId));
        }
    });
```

However the Meeting creation requires an opportunity Id which is a ManyToOne field as defined in their documentations. Is it possible to create a ManyToOne field in java ? If so how ?

This is currently my code for meeting creation, some fields contain dummy values

```
 OdooValues values = new OdooValues();

    values.put("opportunity_id", id); // What to add here ?
    //values.put("id", 1);
    values.put("name", "App Meeting");
    values.put("start", "2019-03-06 00:00:00");
    values.put("stop", "2019-03-07 04:00:00");
    values.put("description", "Test Description");

    client.create("calendar.event", values, new IOdooResponse() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(OdooResult result) {
            int serverId = result.getInt("result");
            Log.d("Meeting Id", String.valueOf(serverId));
        }
    });
```

Comment: You get back the ID of the lead as result of `create` just take it (Integer value) and set this as value in your meeting `create` for `opportunity_id`.

Comment: @CZoellner Thanks it turns out the opportunity was not actually linked to a customer. What about ManyToMany and OneToMany fields ? Thanks

Comment: Have a look at my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55006401/how-to-overwrite-a-one-to-many-records-in-odoo-through-default-api it should also "work" for you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The the lead/opportunity should be created at first. The external API call `create` will give you the ID of the created lead as result, which should be of type integer.

Now take the result and just take it as value for `opportunity_id` which you're already using in the meeting value dictionary (`OdooValues`).